# How to use date and integer as invoice number in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am working on a project where Invoice number should be printed as

```
(ddMMYYYY)+(Int)
```

e.g.

```
07072015001
07072015002
....
07072015110
```

and so on.

I am working with asp.net (C#) and SQL Server as back end.

Please help.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you please be more specific? Show short but complete program demonstrating your problem as well.

Comment: DateTime.Today.ToString("ddMMyyyy") .

Comment: What is your problem? Are you having issues generating the numbers, are you having problems reading the numbers in some particular way? What did you try?

Comment: Which **version** of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: What is Int? is this retrieved from database? if not are you intending to autogenerate? autogenerate and not persisting this information is bad idea as the next time you generate the report will not be the same

Comment: what about on next day? is it reset to 1 like 07/08/2015001 ?
or continue to 07/08/2015111 ?

Comment: yes int has to be auto incremented from database..i am using invoice number as primary key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have an `Invoice` table and it contains at least the `InvoiceID` (`int identity`) and an `InvoiceDate` (of datatype `DATE`), then you could easily just add a computed, persisted column to your table:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Invoices
ADD InvoiceNo AS REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), InvoiceDate, 104), '.', '') + 
    RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 6) + CAST(InvoiceID AS VARCHAR(6)), 6) PERSISTED
```

And thus, if you have a few rows in your table, that `InvoiceNo` would be automagically filled by SQL Server like this:

[image]

This column can be used and read just like any other column - it just cannot be set by you (SQL Server will automatically do that for you as new rows are inserted, or existing rows are updated)

Comment: hi @marc_s, how can I do this by fluent api for code first approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can do following

```
int invoice = 1;
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy") + invoice.ToString();
```

**OutPut**
 070720151

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you looking for? instead of `ddMMYYYY` use `ddMMyyyy`

```
    DateTime myDate = DateTime.Now;
    string strTime = myDate.ToString("ddMMyyyy");
    int intValue=111;

    var invoiceNumber = strTime + intValue.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this one, if you prefer formatting in C#:

```
var invoiceNumber = 2;
var maxWidth = 3;            
var theDate = DateTime.Now;
var formattedValue = theDate.ToString("ddMMyyyy") 
         + invoiceNumber.ToString().PadLeft(maxWidth, '0');
```